# TypeError at /accounts/register/ RegistrationForm() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-rest-framework

accounts/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

accounts/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from accounts.forms import RegistrationForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/accounts')
    else :
        form = RegistrationForm()
        args ={'form':form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/registration_form.html', args)
```

I am getting this error

> TypeError at /accounts/register/ RegistrationForm() takes exactly 1
>   argument (0 given)

Comment: note that it should be `class RegistrationForm`

Comment: use keyword 'class' instead of 'def' RegistrationForm. If you changed please update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use class keyword for your form declaration,

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
```

Also, Your indentation is off, you need to make some changes in your view,

make the args and return statements out of the else part of the if statement.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/accounts')
    else :
        form = RegistrationForm()
    args ={'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/registration_form.html', args)
```

Comment: nope its not working same issues

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: i am unable to add there in my code , it says your code seems to mostly coded

Comment: Internal Server Error: /accounts/register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asif/Desktop/youtube/max/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/asif/Desktop/youtube/max/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)

Comment: File "/home/asif/Desktop/youtube/max/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/asif/Desktop/youtube/max/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/asif/Desktop/youtube/tutorial/accounts/views.py", line 30, in register
    form = RegistrationForm()

Comment: TypeError: RegistrationForm() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: Try instantiating RegistrationForm(None)

Comment: i tried that before , i dont get eroor  but my form fileds doesnt appear in webpage

Comment: Are you satisfied with this answer?

Comment: thanks man i got it

Comment: Could you please do me a favour and tag the answer as selected, then?

Comment: ok done.........